# Можно ли в в установить свои параметры для объекта созданном при помощи класса?

Tags: javascript, ооп, ecmascript-6

Пытаюсь практиковаться в ООП, сделал свой простенький слайдер. И теперь не могу разобраться как правильно при создании объекта задавать для него свои параметры которые будут перезаписывать дефолтные установленные в классе? По типу как в slickslider **ключ:значение** или как-то по другому. Допустим передать другие классы кнопок назад вперёд или установить другое значение **this.interval = 2000;**. И как правильно для параметров задавать значение по умолчанию ? писать в конструкторе **constructor(slider, interval = 2000)**?.

```js
class Slider{
    constructor(slider){
        this.slider = slider;
        this.interval = 2000;
        this.slides= slider.children;
        this.totalSlides = this.slides.length;
        this.containerWidth = this.slider.offsetWidth;
        //Кнопки
        this.nextSlide = document.querySelector('.next-slide');
        this.prevSlide = document.querySelector('.prev-slide');

        var that = this;
        this.nextSlide.onclick= function(){
            that.next();
        };
        this.prevSlide.onclick= function(){
            that.prev();
        };
        this.index=0;
        this.jumpWidth=0;
        // Вызов метода setWidth
        this.setWidth();

    }

    setWidth(){
        var totalWidth = 0;
        for(let i=0; i<this.slides.length;i++){
            this.slides[i].style.width = this.containerWidth + 'px';
            totalWidth = totalWidth + this.containerWidth;
        }
        this.slider.style.width = totalWidth + 'px';
    }

    next(){
        if(this.index==this.totalSlides-1){
            this.index=0;
            this.jumpWidth = 0;
        }
        else{
            this.index++;
            this.jumpWidth = this.jumpWidth+this.containerWidth;
        }
        this.slider.style.marginLeft = -this.jumpWidth + 'px';
    }

    prev(){
        if(this.index==0){
          this.index=this.totalSlides-1;
          this.jumpWidth=this.containerWidth*(this.totalSlides-1);
        }
        else{
           this.index--;
           this.jumpWidth=this.jumpWidth-this.containerWidth;
        }

       this.slider.style.marginLeft=-this.jumpWidth+"px"
    }

}


    const sliderOne=document.querySelector(".slider-items");

    var slider1 = new Slider(sliderOne)


//Что-то по типу этого -->


$('.multiple-items').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

Comment: `constructor(options) { options = { interval: 2000, ...options }; /* todo */ }`. Общий смысл такой. Не забудьте про проверки

Comment: Практиковаться в ООП (в идеале) лучше на языке со статической типизацией.
Ну и на проекте, где много кода, становится понятней, зачем всё это ООП нужно.

Comment: Правильно говорят выше. Лучше объект с параметрами передавать. А в идеале, если с жс норм работаешь, переходи на тайпскрипт. Там такие вопросы проще решаются. Во-первых, можно типизировать этот самый объет с параметрами, т.е. что там должно быть, а чего может не быть, во-вторых nullish coalesing в вопросах типа `this.param = options.time || 2000` (к примеру) подходит куда лучше. Ну это имхо.

Comment: Eще React посмотрите + React хуки, как альтернативу

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, Вроде бы разобрался, но не совсем понял о каких проверках идёт речь ?  И еще если при создании объекта не указать, все параметры в массиве option, то параметры указанные в конструкторе не подтягиваются и выдают андефаинд. Я это обхожу так --> this.param = options.time || 2000?  Но есть ли какой-то другой способ установить параметры по умолчанию не используя nullish coalesing ? Вот код для наглядности. https://codepen.io/RJDio/pen/ExKawQo?editors=1010

Comment: @AlexSazonov this.param = options.time || 2000 это хорошо, но если мы передаём 0, null или false то по умолчанию будет ставится 2000. Я так понял обойти это можно только через if()      if (this.speed === undefined){
      this.speed = false;
    }

Comment: @Dio так я ж и говорю, что такие вещи лучше ТС обрабатывает с помощью nullish coalesing. То есть будет `this.param = options.time ?? 2000`, тогда все `falsy` значения типа 0, пустой строки, и всего такого будут обрабатываться как нужно.

Comment: @Dio, они и не будут "подтягиваться", потому что надо писать так, как я указал выше, и не нужен никакой null coalescing. Проверки: чтобы вам в конструктор не передали, скажем, число

Comment: @Kir_Antipov "писать так, как я указал выше"  constructor(option = {name:'Default',interval: 500,speed:false}) {...}   -- а я разве не так написал, поправьте пожалуйста если не так.  И создание --   var slider = new Slider(option = {
   name:'MyName',
   interval: 2000,
 })

Comment: Я выше указывал параметр по умолчанию? Нет. Их вообще использовать почти никогда не стоит. Ещё раз: `constructor(options) { options = { interval: 2000, speed: 1, ...options }; this.interval = options.interval; this.speed = options.speed; } }` Вызов: `let slider = new Slider({ interval: 500 })`

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Всё благодарю разобрался.  "Не забудьте про проверки" -- единственное так и не понял о каких проверках шла речь. Что нужно проверить?

Comment: @Dio, вызовите `new Slider(3)` и поймёте, о каких проверках шла речь :)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov создал 3 объекта слайдера, запустил все 3, все 3 работают, у каждого свои параметры, всё нормально.  Так и не понял ,что нужно проверять )